# why [NSData bytes] can be changed and impact NSData object itself

Tags: objective-c

Say I have below code from another guy:

```
-(NSString *)xorBetweenString1:(NSString *)str1 andString2:(NSString *)str2 {
    NSData *d1 = [str1 dataUsingEncoding:4];
    const void *b1 = [d1 bytes];

    NSData *d2 = [str2 dataUsingEncoding:4];
    const void *b2 = [d2 bytes];
    const void *b3 = b2;

    int c = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < [d1 length]; i ++) {
        *(Byte *)b1++ ^= *(Byte *)b3++;
        c++;
        if (c == [str2 length]) {
            c = 0;
            b3 = b2;
        }
    }

    NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:d1 encoding:4];
    return result;
}
```

As I remember, [NSData bytes] returns `const void *`, which means the content the pointer points is not mutable. However, above function indeed changes NSData's contents:

before:

> (lldb) po v20
>   <32383a63 663a6461 3a62613a 64313a39 33>

after:

> (lldb) po v20
>   <166c7a31 327a3431 1e362168 30716a69 17>

I am confused, why no errors? Or I made any mistake?

*UPDATE*:
I found [str1 dataUsingEncoding:4] is returning `NSConcreteMutableData`. Seems the root cause. But why it returns `NSConcreteMutableData` instead pure `NSData`? I mean the apple doc never mentioned it?

Comment: I hope this code is generated from disassembler... Also undefined behaviour is undefined. Crash or any runtime error is just best outcome when you are lucky.

Comment: @BryanChen no, the reason I found is it returns NSConcreteMutableData at first place. That's why it's mutable. But why mutable data not NSData?

Comment: Apple doc says it is `NSData`, so it _is_ `NSData`. That's all you need to know. The implementation details is just for performance optimisation and you shouldn't need to know and care about it. Don't write any code depends on it because Apple can change it on next minor OS update without mention it.

Comment: It could very well return a different NSData wrapper depending on what type of encoding you're using. If it's being used as such, it should probably be made mutable. Is it actually breaking something, or were you just curious?

Comment: @rmaddy that's from disassembler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above code is allowed, not because there's a `NSConcreteMutableData` behind the scene, but rather simply because the author is casting a `const` pointer to a non-`const` pointer. In Objective-C, you can bypass all type and mutability safety when you engage in casts.

This mutating of data pointed to by the `bytes` reference is a horrible practice because you have no assurances as to what assumptions or actions this `NSData` may have made with respect to this underlying data buffer. You should be doing a `mutableCopy` to get `NSMutableData` and then working with `mutableBytes` or using one of the `replaceBytes...` methods.

As the `mutableBytes` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsmutabledata/1410770-mutablebytes?language=objc) says:

> This [`mutableBytes`] property is similar to, but different than the `bytes` property. The `bytes` property contains a pointer to a constant. You can use the `bytes` pointer to read the data managed by the data object, but you cannot modify that data. However, if the `mutableBytes` property contains a non-null pointer, this pointer points to mutable data. You can use the `mutableBytes` pointer to modify the data managed by the data object.

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for answering. Could you say more about `because the author is casting a const pointer to a non-const pointer.`? I m not clear here. I see all of them are const void *

Comment: can I have any doc for (Byte *)?

Comment: If you jump to the definition of `Byte` in Xcode, you'll it's just a `typedef` for `UInt8`, which, in turn, is just `typedef` for `unsigned char`. So, this is taking `v19`, casting it to a non-`const` pointer to an `unsigned char`, and then dereferencing that to change the byte to which it pointed.